# Convert timezone specific date to locale using moment

Tags: momentjs

I have the following data for a timezone:

```
{
    "Id": "Pacific Standard Time",
    "DisplayName": "(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
    "StandardName": "Pacific Standard Time",
    "DaylightName": "Pacific Daylight Time",
    "BaseUtcOffset": "-08:00:00",
    "AdjustmentRules": [{
        "DateStart": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "DateEnd": "2006-12-31T00:00:00Z",
        "DaylightDelta": "01:00:00",
        "DaylightTransitionStart": {
            "TimeOfDay": "0001-01-01T02:00:00Z",
            "Month": 4,
            "Week": 1,
            "Day": 1,
            "DayOfWeek": 0,
            "IsFixedDateRule": false
        },
        "DaylightTransitionEnd": {
            "TimeOfDay": "0001-01-01T02:00:00Z",
            "Month": 10,
            "Week": 5,
            "Day": 1,
            "DayOfWeek": 0,
            "IsFixedDateRule": false
        },
        "BaseUtcOffsetDelta": "00:00:00"
    }, {
        "DateStart": "2007-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "DateEnd": "9999-12-31T00:00:00Z",
        "DaylightDelta": "01:00:00",
        "DaylightTransitionStart": {
            "TimeOfDay": "0001-01-01T02:00:00Z",
            "Month": 3,
            "Week": 2,
            "Day": 1,
            "DayOfWeek": 0,
            "IsFixedDateRule": false
        },
        "DaylightTransitionEnd": {
            "TimeOfDay": "0001-01-01T02:00:00Z",
            "Month": 11,
            "Week": 1,
            "Day": 1,
            "DayOfWeek": 0,
            "IsFixedDateRule": false
        },
        "BaseUtcOffsetDelta": "00:00:00"
    }],
    "SupportsDaylightSavingTime": true
}
```

and the following date:

```
2019-01-05T07:30:07Z
```

Using moment, i'd like to convert this to my current locale which is

```
en-GB
```

How do i go about doing this with momentjs?

the problem seems to be that the date format i have is not compatible with moment.

I've prepared a jsfiddle with variables that i have access to:

http://jsfiddle.net/jimmyt1988/xe7ha5ms/1/

Comment: Do you want to convert `2019-01-05T07:30:07` (Pacific Standard Time => IANA timezone `America/Los_Angeles`) to `Europe/London` displaying it using en-GB locale with momentjs?

Comment: Yes, from Pacific Standard Time -> a locale of en-GB. the problem seems to be that the date format i have is not compatible with moment

Comment: @VincenzoC - I've updated my question with a jsfiddle that might help understand what issues i'm coming up with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input is in ISO 8601 format recognized by moment. You can parse it using [`moment.tz`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/):

> The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the moment constructor, but uses the last argument as [a time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

then you can convert it to desired timezone using [`tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/):

> The `moment#tz` mutator will change the time zone and update the offset.

You can set locale on a moment object using [`locale()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) and then use [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to display value.

Here a code sample:

```js
console.log(
  moment.tz('2019-01-05T07:30:07', 'America/Los_Angeles') // parse input in given tz
    .tz('Europe/London') // Convert moment to desired zone
    .locale('en-gb') // set en-gb locale
    .format('LLLL') // display result
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer as it deals with the question more thoroughly. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, by using the utcOffset method:

http://jsfiddle.net/jimmyt1988/xe7ha5ms/2/

```
moment("2019-01-05T07:30:07Z")
.utcOffset("-08:00:00")
.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Please note that (from [`utcOffset`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) docs) : once you set an offset, it's fixed and won't change on its own (i.e there are no DST rules). If you want an actual time zone -- time in a particular location, like `America/Los_Angeles`, consider [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).